# Application url not working within office network

Tags: jsp, servlets

I've deployed one application developed using Java-Struts on one of my
client's office. Application is web-based - So we hosted it on one the machine available
in client's office - using static ip. 
The application runs fine outside client's office network. But when we were testing the 
application within client's environment - we came across odd issue.

There is a dashboard page in the application. This page has a table which list down cases
listed for a particular day (Screen shot of the page attached). There is an "Update" column 
for each case, click on this and it takes you to "Maintain Case Diary" page (This whole 
fuctionality works just fine outside client's office network).
Now when client has to access the application within their network they use following url
http://192.168.1.12:8080/CTS/
Now if we click on "Update" link on Dashboard page - it just shows progress bar on browser.
It does not take us to "Maintain Case Diary" page. It is also not showing any error on
browser or in log file.

Following url is shown in browser (withing office network - Not Working)
http://192.168.1.12:8080/CTS/CaseDetailController?action=update&CaseMasterID=225

Following url is shown in browser (Outside office network - This is Working)
http://99.99.999.999:8080/CTS/CaseDetailController?action=update&CaseMasterID=225

I hope I've explained the issue in detail, Thank you very much in advance.

[image: Dashboard]

JSP Page Code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <div class="panel panel-red" style="width: auto;" >
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="width: auto;" >
                                        <h3 class="panel-title" style="width: auto;"  ><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Daily Board</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="overflow:scroll;height:400px;width:auto; overflow:auto">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Update</th>  
                                                    <th>Register No</th>  
                                                    <th>Case Number</th>
                                                    <th>File Name</th>
                                                    <th>Current Date</th>                                                                       
                                                    <th>Stage</th>
                                                    <th>Judge</th>                                                                                           
                                                    <th>Court</th>                                           
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <c:forEach items="${casedetails}" var="casedetail">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><a href="CaseDetailController?action=update&CaseMasterID=<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_ID}"/>">UPDATE</a></td>                                                        
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.cad_RegNo}" /></td>                                                
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.cad_CaseNo}" /></td>
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.cad_FileName}" /></td>                                                        
                                                        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${casedetail.ccd_CurrentDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yy" /></td>
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Stage}" /></td>  
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Judge}" /></td> 
                                                        <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Court}" /></td>                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                    </tr>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
        int CaseMasterID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("CaseMasterID"));
        request.setAttribute("casemaster", dao.getCaseMasterById(CaseMasterID));
        request.setAttribute("casedetail", dao.getCaseDetailById(CaseMasterID));
        request.setAttribute("casemasters", dao.getAllCaseMaster());
        request.setAttribute("advocates", dao.getAllAdvocate());
        request.setAttribute("casestages", dao.getAllCaseStage());
        request.setAttribute("courts", dao.getAllCourt());
        request.setAttribute("casedetails", dao.getAllCaseDetailByID(CaseMasterID));
        request.setAttribute("casemdetail", dao.getLastCaseDetailByID(CaseMasterID));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/RNDctsCaseDetailRegistration.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the the typo -

Comment: Here is the url. Following url is shown in browser (withing office network - Not Working) http://192.168.1.12:8080/CTS/CaseDetailController?action=update&CaseMasterID=225

Comment: Is the client connecting via a mobile device? Because that could cause some problems with DNS lookups on a LAN.

Comment: Client also tried accessing it using Desktop within the network, they are facing same issue.

Comment: You may need to change the address that your server is listening on to 0.0.0.0. Maybe the pages are only being served on the interface that connects to the public Internet.

Comment: But then shouldn't it happen for every single page? I tried accessing other pages of the application... its working fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the server's log to see if it is receiving the requests?

Comment: I found this when I executed the application through netbeans IDE in log...

Comment: 03-Jul-2017 13:12:42.503 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [CaseDetailController] in context with path [/CTS] threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
 at com.cts.controller.CaseDetailController.doGet(CaseDetailController.java:136)

Comment: This means that inside your else-if you're forwarding the request and then at the end of your method you're trying to forward the same request again

Comment: Looks like I found the root cause of this issue -  The statement I've written in my controller   (Code is mentioned above ) "request.getRequestDispatcher("/RNDctsCaseDetailRegistration.jsp").forward(request, response);" I just changed it to "forward = LIST_DAIRY_SEARCH;". It appears to be working on my laptop. I just need to visit client's office tomorrow morning and see if this works there. If yes, I'll close the question. Thank you very much Dziugas... I'll keep you posted on this issue.

Comment: Please close if the above stuff works for you!

Comment: Hi Shivam - please give me just 2-3 hours. I've visiting client's office after a while. I'll test it in their office and close the question right away. I hope that is alright...